# Evaluation of log density for various values of `mean`

Tags: numpy, scipy

I can evaluate the log probability density of a multivariate normal by doing

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.logpdf([0,0], mean = np.zeros(2), cov = np.eye(2))
```

Now, I'm interested in evaluating the log density of the point `[0,0]` over a variety of values of mean.  Here is what I have tried

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

grid = np.linspace(-2,2,51)
x,y = np.meshgrid(grid,grid)
scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.logpdf([0,0], mean = np.stack([x,y], axis = -1), cov = np.eye(2))
```

This results in an error: `ValueError: Array 'mean' must be a vector of length 5202.`

How can I evaluate the log density of a multivariate normal over a variety of values of `mean`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error suggest `logpdf` is waiting a 1D array for the `mean` argument. 
Since  your covariance matrix is 2x2, you should give him a 2x1 array to `mean`.

If you want to evaluate the density for multiple mean values you can use a for loop after flattening `x` and `y` as follows :

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

grid = np.linspace(-2,2,51)
x,y = np.meshgrid(grid,grid)

x,y = x.flatten(), y.flatten()

res = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    x_i, y_i = x[i], y[i]
    res.append(scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.logpdf([0,0], mean =[x_i,y_i], cov = np.eye(2)))
```

You can also also use list comprehension in place of the for loop :

```py
res = [scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.logpdf([0,0], mean =[x_i,y_i], cov = np.eye(2)) for i in range(len(x))]
```

To visualize the result you can use `matplotlib.pyplot` :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,y,c=res)
plt.show()
```

But I don't see the point of trying to evaluate the multivariate gaussian logpdf over several mean values.

In the case of a multivariate normal distribution the argument x and the mean m have symmetric roles as you can see in the exponential term : (x-m)^T Sigam^(-1) (x-m).

What you are doing is equivalent to evaluate the logpdf of a multivariate gaussian of mean `[0,0]` and of covariance `eye(2)`.

Comment: So there is no way to vectorize the computation?  The evaluation of the gaussian log density over many values of the mean is useful in computing log posterior densities in bayesian analyses.  In any case, if the computation can't be vectorized, a loop is fine.

Comment: you can vectorize with::
```python
res=scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.logpdf(np.stack([x,y], axis = -1), mean=[0,0], cov = np.eye(2))
```
Where x, y are your values of mean.
Since the mean and x have symmetric roles as I said earlier, it will give you the same result that when you set x and change the mean value.
Because if you see the pdf as a function of x, or if you see it as a function of the mean, it is at the end the same function from R^N to R.  
I don't know if I am clear, let me know.

Comment: No that make sense. Its not really the answer I was hoping for, but that isn't a big deal.  Thanks